# Does this count as a SEO-Friendly URL?

Tags: seo

Does this count as a SEO-Friendly URL

```
http://store-uk.onlineshop.com/women/10000,en_GB,sc.html
```

Or does the fact that it has 10000,en_GB,sc.html  at the end cancel it out?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

Most SEO-friendly URLs for online shops will have the product title in the URL itself. Your URL only indicates that it's a UK store selling something for women. The `10000,en_GB,sc.html` serves no use for SEO or for the customer.
For example, Amazon uses SEO-friendly URLS. [http://www.amazon.com/SEO-2014-Beyond-Search-optimization/dp/1494401894](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1494401894)

The first part of the URL `http://www.amazon.com/` is the website, the next part is the product name `SEO-2014-Beyond-Search-optimization` and the last part `/dp/1494401894` is some id for the product. The URL tells the user the link is in relation to SEO. If only the id was shown, then they wouldn't know.